# DataGrip copy all text inside a cell with limit

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

How to copy all text in a cell without changing the cell limit size ?

[image: example DataGrip cell with limit]

Answer (score 2):

The current workaround is to use *Save to file* which loads (and then saves) the full data.

Please see and follow [DBE-9310](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9310) to support it natively.